Torchvision, detection inference on very large images
I trained a Mask R-CNN model from TorchVision to detect/segment a class of object. I trained the model on 512x512 patches/crops, but now I need to apply it on VERY big images (50Kx50K).
Is there a function that automatically takes care of applying a model to bigger images and deals with keeping the detection consistent?
Because the biggest problem will be when an object is partially detected on two adjacent patches, and needs to be reconstructed as a single object.

I don't know of any library that does this for you, but you need to break the image into patches of 512x512, then reassemble the patch predictions back into a full image. You handle partial detections by adding overlap to your patches

Thanks. I know that, I did it for segmentation already. I wish to know if a function already does it

Here is a solution: https://github.com/obss/sahi
